# Thread.ResetAbort() on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8

I've this exception :

> Thread was being aborted

when I call the Abort() method on a thread. I catch the exception but it still stops the application.

I tried `Thread.ResetAbort()` but it's not supported on windows phone 8...
 Is there an other solution to do continue the execution of the app when this exception is caught?

Comment: You should show the code where you are catching the exception.

Comment: The solution here is to not use `Abort`, but rather use cooperative cancellation such that the other thread can only be canceled when it is in a position where it can safely support cancellation.

Comment: I'm going to try your solution Servy. Any good tutorial?

Comment: Two useful links about how to use cancellation [link1](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx), [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx), just in case ;)